# Add in loop 7 days to a date with input hidden

Tags: javascript, date

I know there's a lot of posts about this but i cannot find my error... Im trying to simply update an input hidden with a date that i up to 7 days in loop (for each click)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showCalendar();

    $('body').on('click', '.datePick', function() {
        var newDate = $('#dateNow'); // INPUT HIDDEN WITH YYYY-MM-DD STRING

        showCalendar(newDate);
    });
});

function showCalendar(dateF) {
    if((dateF == '')||(dateF == null)) {
        var today = new Date();

        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) { dd='0'+dd; } 
        if(mm<10) { mm='0'+mm; } 

        dateToday = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    } else {
        dateToday = dateF;
    }

    // DO SOMETHING IN AJAX

    // AND NEXT UPDATE THE HIDDEN FIELD WITH +7 DAYS
    upDayDate(dateToday);
}

function upDayDate(dateToUp) {
    var myDate = new Date(dateToUp);
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+7);

    $('#dateNow').val(myDate);
}
```

The first time the script is launched (with document ready) everything is OK, but all other times we pass throught "upDayDate" i have error. Ive tryed several methods and always have : invalid Date, or NaN... Thanks

P.S : also tryied :

```
    function upDayDate(dateToUp) {
    var newdate = new Date(dateToUp);

    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + 7);

    var dd = ('0' + newdate.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var mm = ('0' + (newdate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
    var y = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = y+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;

    $('#dateNow').val(someFormattedDate);
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't answer your question but I highly recommend https://momentjs.com/ for working with dates, it's a small library worth every kilobyte when working with dates.

Comment: Please click `<>` and create a [mcve] with expected and actual output

Comment: @digital-pollution - moment.js is huge overkill in this case

Comment: Thanks, will take a look (looks very simply !), but I would also like to understand my mistake.. Curiosity ... ! ^^

Comment: $('#dateNow').val(myDate); is not "2018-05-01" in your upDayDate

Comment: it's not really, if you need to do anything significant with javascript dates.

Comment: @digital-pollution adding 7 days is not signiifcant

Comment: which is why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @mplungjan i know, the function "upDayDate" was just an exemple, all my functions fail, ive just update my post with an other one which return "invalid date"

Comment: var newDate = $('#dateNow'); have to by changed by var newDate = $('#dateNow').val();
It was a very big mistake... My fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you always get and want to set yyyy-mm-dd you need to do this:

```js
function pad(num) {
  return ("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
function yyyymmdd(d) {
  return d.getFullYear()+"-"+pad(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+pad(d.getDate());
}
function upDayDate(d) {
    d.setDate(d.getDate()+7);
    $('#dateNow').val(yyyymmdd(d));
}
function showCalendar(dateF) {
  if(dateF)) {
    parts = dateF.split("-");
    dateToday =  new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],0,0,0);
  }
  else dateToday = new Date();
    // DO SOMETHING IN AJAX

    // AND NEXT UPDATE THE HIDDEN FIELD WITH +7 DAYS
  upDayDate(dateToday); // maybe in the success?
}
```

Comment: It's full of errors (split, getDate etc.), will try to fix all of this and i tell you if it works

Comment: Okay main problem was : var newDate = $('#dateNow'); .... Ive replaced it by : var newDate = $('#dateNow').val(); with your ajustements and everything works fine now. Thanks

Comment: Yikes - missed that

Comment: @Siln6 If you next time create a [mcve] then it is easier to test. I did not want to create a date picker etc to test the code you provided.